# Set the selected index of a Dropdown using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I set the index of a dropdown in jQuery if the way I'm finding the control is as follows:

```
$("*[id$='" + originalId + "']")
```

I do it this way because I'm creating controls dynamically and since the ids are changed when using Web Forms, I found this as a work around to find me some controls. But once I have the jQuery object, I do not know how to set the selected index to 0 (zero).

Answer (score 385, accepted):

First of all - that selector is pretty slow.  It will scan every DOM element looking for the ids.  It will be less of a performance hit if you can assign a class to the element.

```
$(".myselect")
```

To answer your question though, there are a few ways to change the select elements value in jQuery

```
// sets selected index of a select box to the option with the value "0"
$("select#elem").val('0'); 

// sets selected index of a select box to the option with the value ""
$("select#elem").val(''); 

// sets selected index to first item using the DOM
$("select#elem")[0].selectedIndex = 0;

// sets selected index to first item using jQuery (can work on multiple elements)
$("select#elem").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Comment: is there a better way to do it? I figured it'd scan the whole DOM looking to match the ID, but since I'm new to jQuery I figured, let's make it work and then see if there's a better way to do it. Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes - if you can assign a class to the element(s) you need to find, it would be a much faster selector.

Comment: @gnarf aren't IDs faster?

Comment: `#an-id` is faster, but `*[id$=ends-with]` is way slower, thats what the "assign a class to the element" is meaning

Comment: How about if I have multiple ASP.net DropDownList with different selected index value?

Comment: Correct answer, but also check answer of PaulG: To make the dropbox update visually as well, `$("select#elem").val('0').change()` can be used for _both_ selecting and updating the UI.

Comment: How to scroll to first element of multiselect in IE, but preserving all elements selected??

Comment: if you can't add a class to the element(s), `$("select[id$='" + originalId + "']")` is at least oodles faster than `$("*[id$='" + originalId + "']")`

Comment: the last option is the best imo

Answer (score 110):

Just found this, it works for me and I personally find it easier to read.

This will set the actual index just like gnarf's answer number 3 option.

```
// sets selected index of a select box the actual index of 0 
$("select#elem").attr('selectedIndex', 0);
```

This didn't used to work but does now... see bug:
http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1474

### Addendum

As recommended in the comments use :

`$("select#elem").prop('selectedIndex', 0);`

Comment: And as of jQuery 1.6 you should be using `.prop('selectedIndex', 0);` regardless of if `.attr()` works or not :)

Comment: Correct, it in fact might not work in 1.7. see accepted answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010664/jquery-1-7-this-attrtype-for-select-gives-undefined-instaed-of-select-on

Comment: +1 for the addendum. My old code got broken due to this issue

Comment: Website I'm working is using jQuery v3.3.1 and `.attr()` did not work; using `.prop()` did though. Thanks bois

Answer (score 13):

I'm writing this answer in 2015, and for some reason (probably older versions of jQuery) none of the other answers have worked for me. I mean, they change the selected index, but it doesn't actually reflect on the actual dropdown.

Here is another way to change the index, and actually have it reflect in the dropdown:

```
$('#mydropdown').val('first').change();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only this answer is worked for me

Comment: Also in 2015, I have no problem with `prop('selectedIndex', ...);` (tested with Chrome & Firefox) changing the selection.

Comment: For what it's worth, it should be pointed out that you're doing different here is triggering a `change` event on the drop-down, which could also be a useful fix/workaround for people who are changing the selection by calling `prop('selectedIndex', ...)`, rather than `val(...)`. Perhaps the problem was that you're listening for a `change` event, and THAT's what wasn't working for you? It's true that simply changing the `prop`erty is not going to fire any events...

Answer (score 10):

JQuery code:

```
$("#sel_status").prop('selectedIndex',1);
```

Jsp Code:

```
Status:
<select name="sel_status"
    id="sel_status">
    <option value="1">-Status-</option>
    <option>ALL</option>
    <option>SENT</option>
    <option>RECEIVED</option>
    <option>DEACTIVE</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm using

```
$('#elem').val('xyz');
```

to select the option element that has value='xyz'

Answer (score 4):

You want to grab the value of the first option in the select element.

```
$("*[id$='" + originalId + "']").val($("*[id$='" + originalId + "'] option:first").attr('value'));
```

Answer (score 4):

To select the 2nd option

```
$('#your-select-box-id :nth-child(2)').prop('selected', true);
```

---

Here we add the `trigger('change') to make the event fire.

```
$('#your-select-box-id :nth-child(2)').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
```

Comment: this is a much better answer.

Answer (score 3):

This also work proper in chrome and internet Explorer

```
$("#MainContent_cmbEvalStatus").prop("selectedIndex", 1).change();
```

Put according your choice possition value of DropDown 0,1,2,3,4.....

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[id$='" + originalId + "']").val("0 index value");
```

will set it to 0

Comment: Not sure if this is just old but does not work Jan 2022

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou I was referring to something similar to MacAnthonys response. You are not meant to include the actual text of `0 index value` but the value of the option that is the 0 index. His answer dynamically pulls the value of the option at the 0 index so would result in the same thing except his would work in any scenario due to not having to hardcode the value.

Answer (score 1):

Select 4th option

```
$('#select').val($('#select option').eq(3).val());
```

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dabar/jwNyV/)

Comment: valid solution... for a code-obfuscation contest! :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Init () {
            var counter = document.getElementById ("counter");
            for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
                var option = new Option (i, i);
                counter.options.add (option);
            }
            counter.focus ();
        }
        
        function OnKeyPressCounter (event, counter) {
            var chCode = ('charCode' in event) ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
        
            if (chCode == 68 /* + */) {
                if (counter.selectedIndex < counter.options.length - 1) {
                    counter.selectedIndex++;
                }
            }
            if (chCode == 45 /* - */) {
                if (counter.selectedIndex > 0) {
                    counter.selectedIndex--;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Init ()">
    Use the + and - keys to increase/decrease the counter.
    <select id="counter" onkeypress="OnKeyPressCounter(event, this)" style="width:80px"></select>
</body>
```