# Getting the type of a control using Javascript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, controls

I am trying to use JQuery to get the type of control and following is the code that I am using.

```
$('#selCity').attr('type')
```

where selCity is of type select. When I try the above code it returns as undefined but when I use the alternative code with Javascript, it returns the correct type.

Please look into this fiddle to understand it clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/Ye8e9/

Could someone advice on how I can acheive this correctly using JQuery? Is this an issue with JQuery or am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
$('#selCity').prop('type')
```

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. In addition, .attr() should not be used on
>   plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and
>   change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010664/jquery-1-7-this-attrtype-for-select-gives-undefined-instaed-of-select-on)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ye8e9/2/)

Comment: @AbishekRSrikaanth check my reference

Comment: @AbishekRSrikaanth you can use .prop for all type html elements, check my demo

Answer (score 8):

if you mean the type of tag, the use this

```
 $("#selCity").get(0).tagName
```

[**See your demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ye8e9/1/)

Comment: Rab Nawaz, Is there a generic approach that I can follow to get for all the controls. If I try the above code for a textbox, I get the value "INPUT" and with this output am not sure if the control is a hidden field or a textbox or a password field.

Answer (score 0):

Use nodeName to get 'type of Tag'. '.type' refers to attribute 'type' which select doesn't have.

```
document.getElementById('selCity').nodeName
```

Comment: Am not sure or dont understand by what you mean by attribute 'type' does not exist for select control. How does javascript output data when the following code is executed

document.getElementById('selCity').type

Answer (score 0):

you are getting undefined because there is not type attribute in select.

try this one

```
$('#selCity')[0].tagName;
```