# javascript function breaks drop-down menus but just in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, firefox

For some reason this function is doing something weird just in Firefox

```
function fadeOUT_sect(id) {
    if ( $("div#"+id).css("display")!="none") {
        $("div#"+id).fadeOut();
        $("div#"+id).find("ul").each(function() {
            var name = $(this).attr("id");
            $(this).find("input").removeAttr("checked");
            if ( $(this).find("select > option:first").val() != "-9" ) {
                $(this).find("select > option:first").attr({
                    value:"-9",
                    selected:"selected"
                }); // $.attr()
            } // if select

            // I've isolated the problem to this if-test
            if ( !($(this).find('input[value="-9"]').val()) ) {
            //   ^ I think the problem is here.
                $(this).find('input[type="text"]').val('');
                $(this).append('<input name="'+name+'" type="radio" value="-9" checked="checked" />');
            } // if

        }); // $.each()
    } // if
} // function
```

Initially, the HTML where the problem appears looks like this:

```
<div id="2" style="display:none">
<ul id="state">
    <li>What state do you live in?</li>
    <li><select>
        <option value="-9" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        …
    </select></li>
</ul>
```

After a `fadeIn()`, `div#2` is visible and the first `<option>` becomes `<option value=""></option>` and when I click on the dropdown menu, I see all of my options. Now the trouble begins:

When I select an option, the dropdown goes away, but the bar/bubble is blank (and I didn't select the blank option). I click the dropdown again, and my option is highlighted in the list; I click away, and the bar/bubble is blank again. I click the dropdown a third time, select the blank option, click away, click back, and select a non-blank option, and all of a sudden I can see text in the bar/bubble.

The trouble *only* occurs in Firefox <s>(possibly just for Mac)</s> on both Mac and Windows. No trouble in Windows or Mac for any of the following: Safari/Chrome, Opera, IE7+ (IE6 just can't display the page at all).

**EDIT** I tested this in Firefox, Safari/Chrome, and Opera on multiple computers, and got the same result (so no cache/data issue).

**EDIT 2** Here's the problem reproduced in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JakobJingleheimer/EkDdB/3/

**EDIT 3**: I just tested Firefox versions 5 thru 9, and *this problem occurs in **Firefox 8+***. In reading the release notes on v8, it seems they started using "Type inference" for javascript (but I don't know how that might affect anything or how to get round it if it does).

Thanks!

**[Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8797050/758177)**: Remove `selected="selected"` in the html, and removed `selected:"selected"` from `.attr({…})` and `.removeAttr("selected")` in the javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Please oh please cache your selected elements! `var $div = $('#' + id); $div.css..., $div.fadeOut...,` etc. Now I'll see if I can find your problem.

Comment: Set this up in a jsFiddle and I'll take a closer look.

Comment: How do you call the above function? Also, it won't break it, but why do you say $("div#"+id) rather than $("#"+id)? (Given that id is unique the "div" part doesn't help at all.)

Comment: Can you add more info?  The code and description you gave will take a lot of legwork to create a repro of the scenario you're describing.  I tried copying it in as-is, and adding an invocation to the function, and I am not seeing what you're talking about yet.  It will be very helpful to add enough code to make a complete demo, and to *also* post that code on a demo app made using jsfiddle.net

Comment: Need to see full code to know when and where fade in/out functions get called.

Comment: "2" is not a legal ID for an html element. I am not sure if this is your problem, but given this is a browser-specific issue, seems like a possibility. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @jamietre I fixed the div id (+1 for that catch! but it didn't fix it. ps that's a pain that it must start with /a-z/i)

Comment: here it is in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/EkDdB/

Comment: @nnnnnn i just created a fiddle for it (see the question for an updated link)

Comment: @jacob This seems to work just fine for me in Firefox. What version are you using?

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker I've checked it in Ffx 8 & 9 on both Mac and PC.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Firefox 9.0.1 on Windows 7 x64. Maybe one of your add-ons or extensions?

Comment: Checked in FF 9.0.1 both on Win and Mac - works fine.

Comment: Checked it in FireFox 10 as well - works fine.

Comment: @Domenic I disabled all of my extensions/add-ons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the error on Firefox 8.0.1 for Mac.

The problem is coming from the line I have commented out below.

```
function fadeIN_sect(id) {
    $("#" + id + ' > ul > input[value="9999"]').remove();
    //$("#" + id + " > ul > li > select > option:first").attr("value", "").removeAttr("selected");
    $("#" + id).fadeIn();
}
```

Once I commented that line out it works fine. You could try separating the lines and debugging each action one at a time.

Edit: Testing seems to point to the removeAttr call. Also as noted in the comments above don't forget to cache all your selectors. It's very inefficient to keep selecting them.

Comment: Yep! It was the `selected="selected"`. I'm not sure if it was the javascript `removeAttr("selected")` or that the html had `selected="selected"`, but I didn't need the javascript after I removed the hard-coded attribute from the html. (I had hard-coded `selected` so I wouldn't have to rely on the browser's choice of which element to select by default). Thanks!! +50

Comment: Oh, btw do you know how else I should do this?

Comment: @jacob I'm fairly sure that the browser won't select anything other than the first value? Do you have evidence otherwise?

Comment: My problem is I hide the `select` and I need force the selected option to go back to the first (in case the user has selected a different option).

Comment: @jacob Simply set the selectedIndex to 0. You can do this with jQuery as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314245/set-the-selected-index-of-a-dropdown-using-jquery