# jQuery select box .val('') behavior differs from 1.9 to 1.10+ what is the shortest way to do that

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following behaves differently between jQuery 1.9 and 1.10+:

```
<select id="s1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

$('#s1 option[value=1]').hide();
$('#s1').val('');
```

The idea behind this code is to select the first option.

After 1.10, the `$('#s1').val('');` part is no longer working in the same way. I suppose that it was never meant to be used that way but its old code and have to be modernized in some way...

After jQuery 1.10 nothing is selected and `$('#s1').val()` returns `null`.

Changing code to:

```
$('#s1 option[value=1]').hide();
$('#s1').val($('#s1 option').first().val());
```

Does the job with both new and old jQuery versions.

My question is if there is shorter/more elegant way to do the same thing?

Comment: can you please elaborate 'no longer working in the same way'?

Comment: What do you mean by `$('#s1').val('');`? To select the first option?

Comment: [1.9.1 Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/979HZ/) vs [1.10.1 Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/979HZ/1/)

Comment: `$('#s1').prop('selectedIndex', 0);`

Comment: Sorry all for pasting the wrong part of the code - the problematic behavious is present on .hide(), and it works just fine on .remove()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#s1")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

You can also do this if you really like jQuery:

```
$("#s1").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
```

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1314266/283863

Comment: both does not work, if the first option is hidden; anyways selected your answer as most close...

Answer (score 2):

Just don't set the value it selects first value automatically and works in both versions:

```
$('#s1 option[value=1]').remove();
//$('#s1').val('');
```

[demo version: 1.9.1](http://jsfiddle.net/Ngaqk/1/) and [demo version: 1.10.1](http://jsfiddle.net/Ngaqk/3/)

---

As per your update and comments, you can use like this:

```
$('#s1 option[value=1]').hide();
$('#s1 option[value=2]').hide();
$('#s1 option:visible').first().attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/979HZ/4/)

Comment: +1 because you are right for .remove but the problem is with .hide

Comment: how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/Ngaqk/4/

Comment: yep, it works but i need generic way, because the first visible option is not known in advance

Comment: then you should use as Darek http://jsfiddle.net/Ngaqk/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/979HZ/2/ - check this, the selectedIndex property counts hidden items too

Comment: Still does not work ok - it displays 1, while this option is hidden. The problem with all approaches above is that both selected index and .first() also return and count hidden options. I am going to ask a new question with more properly formulating the problem itself

Comment: in more refined way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444264/jquery-how-select-the-first-non-hidden-select-option