# jQuery how to select the first non-hidden select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following behaves differently between jQuery 1.9 and 1.10+:

```
<select id="s1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

$('#s1 option[value=1]').hide();
$('#s1').val('');
```

The idea behind this code is to select the first non-hidden option, after hiding some options, including the currently selected one.

Since jQuery 1.10+ the `$('#s1').val('');` no longer selects the first non-hidden option, while `.val(<some proper value for the particular select box>)` works ok.

Trying the following approaches does not help because both `selectedIndex` and `.first().val()` consider the hidden options:

`$("#s1").prop("selectedIndex", 0);`

`$('#s1 option').first().prop('selected', true);`

Next thing that comes to mind (also suggested by [C-link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138752/c-link)) also does not work, because the `:visible` selector does not work properly for select options.

`$('#s1 option:visible').first().prop('selected', true);`

Looking for some generic way (not depending on knowledge of what are the particular values and what options have been hidden) to achieve the same behaviour as `$('#s1').val('');` in old jQuery.

Comment: Why are you hiding options? What is the real end goal of your questions?

Comment: Are you pretty much repeating your question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443642/jquery-select-box-val-behavior-differs-from-1-9-to-1-10-what-is-the-shorte?lq=1

Comment: @phpLearner yep, because it was not formulated well and got marked as duplicate

Comment: @Ian - do you suggest to remove/readd them instead?

Comment: `remove()` will work here.http://jsfiddle.net/J3DGV/

Comment: @bbonev I don't know, maybe. Explain what you're trying to do with all this

Comment: what is not working I've shown you the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/979HZ/4/ not?

Comment: @C-link it should display 3, but its showing 1 while only 3 is in the drop down. http://jsfiddle.net/979HZ/9/ is what I have compiled from all answers and comments.

Comment: it's showing 3 in my fiddle and in your fiddle too.

Comment: umm, try prop instead of attr once..

Comment: In FF both work, in Chrome yours is not working; no matter prop/attr.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Compiled from everybody else's answers/comments the following:

```
$('#s1 option').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
        $(this).prop("selected", true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Shortly Like this:

```
$('#s1').find("option:not(:hidden):eq(0)");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<select id="s1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

$('#s1 option[value=1]').hide();

var firstVisibleValue = '';
$('#s1').children().each(function(){  //iterate options

    //check if option is visible - if not set to display none, which is what `.hide` does.
    if($(this).css('display') != 'none'){  
        firstVisibleValue = $(this).val();
        return false;   //stop iterating
    }
});
$('#s1').val(firstVisibleValue);
```

Comment: Instead the global `firstVisibleValue = $(this).val();` it may just `$('#s1').val($(this).val())`; anyways I am starting to consider regenerating the whole boxes instead of hide/show-ing options

Answer (score 2):

maybe this:

```
$('#s1').find("option:not([hidden]):eq(0)");
```

Comment: Yes. It works but it should be in the following format:
`$('#s1').find("option:not(:hidden):eq(0)");`
Instead of `[hidden]` it should be `:hidden`

Comment: In what version? As seen in this fiddle, in both 1.9.1 and 1.10.0 versions it works properly using the [hidden] attribute selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using class

```js
$('#s1 option[value=1]').hide();
$('#s1 option[value=1]').addClass('hidden');
$('#s1 option[value=1]').removeClass('visible')
$('#s1').val('');
$('#s1 .visible:first').val();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
    <option class="visible" value="1">1</option>
    <option class="visible" value="2">2</option>
    <option class="visible" value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Good suggestion, I changed it to a class and it just worked as expected. I would simplify it by having a single class called 'hidden' and use CSS .hidden {display: none;}.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
$('#s1 option[value="1"]').hide();

$('#s1').find('option').each(function()
 {
if($(this).is(':visible'))
{
    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
    return false;
}
 });
```

Comment: `is(':visible')` does not work, exactly like `$('#s1 option:visible')`