# How can i reset a selectpicker after hide a modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, dropdownbox, jquery-selectbox

(sorry my english)

Hey , well i have a select picker:

```
                    +                       
                    '<select class="selectpicker" id="select_seleccionar_proyecto_id">'
                    +
                    '<option value="0">Seleccione..</option>'
                    +                           
                    '<option value="1">Tarea número 1</option>'
                    +                           
                    '<option value="2">Tarea número 2</option>'
                    +                       
                    '<option value="3">Tarea número 3</option>'
                    +
                    '<option value="4">Tarea número 4</option>'
                    +                           
                    '<option value="5">Tarea número 5</option>'
                    +                       
                    '<option value="6">Tarea número 6</option>' 
                    +                   
                    '</select>'
```

this select box is in a modal, and when i close this modal, the select box is like the last time , example: i select "tarea numero 4", i close the modal and open the modal and "tarea numero 4" is selected. Well, i have a method that i call after hide the modal and when i open i need "seleccionar..", but nothing work..

¿what is the best option in jquery? thanks

```
HideModal: function(){
    var self = this;
    $('#modal_seleccionar_tarea_id').modal('hide');
    self.LimpiarModalTarea();
    },

LimpiarModalTarea: function(){
var self = this;

 $('#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id').val("0");},
```

PD : this work in other modal, but with textarea.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap-select

```
$("selectorOfSelect").val('0').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for this `$("#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id").prop('selectedIndex',0);`

stackoverflow [Set the selected index of a Dropdown using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314245/set-the-selected-index-of-a-dropdown-using-jquery)

Comment: selected index not suppose to be access by jQuery object. You need to add `$("#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id")[0].selectedIndex = 0;` to access `selectedIndex` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your jquery code

**from**

```
$('#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id').val("0");
```

**into**

```
$("#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
               //<<--  or
$("#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
```

Normally, by using `$('#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id').val("0");` also work, is that `LimpiarModalTarea` function work when called in `hidemodal` function?? If did't ensure those function work by putting an alert to ensure that.

Comment: thanks for answer, but doesn't work, and yes, if i put an alert in "LimpiarModalTarea" and i close the modal, the alert work.. so i know that the method is fine , because is the same that i used before, but with a textarea in a modal.

Comment: Can you add your code on fiddle. Easy for us to see what happened there.