# Set the Option Value of Select with jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to set the value 'Saumon' of the following select as default value with jquery if condition is met. I know how to deal with conditions but really don't find a solution to this issue :

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: block;">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2">Sandwiches 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select id="ordersdetailpartyloafsandwich1ID" name="child-partyloafsandwich1ID" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Saumon</option>
        </select>
        <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 100px;">
            <span class="selection">
                <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-ordersdetailpartyloafsandwich1ID-container">
                    <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-ordersdetailpartyloafsandwich1ID-container" title="Saumon">Saumon</span>
                <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

I have tried this :

```
https://jsfiddle.net/marcq/rL4nuhv6/1/
```

but the value is of course set outside the select box.

I'm stuck and would appreciate some expertise here since I don't want to alter the source code of my app. Thanks. Marc

Comment: I didn't get your question. Please explain a bit more

Comment: You only have to set the value of select it will automatically select the proper option. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aalok123/846hbz2g/4/

Comment: @Alok Mali Thank you to have understood my question ;-) Your solution did it, but I'm unable to accept your answer which is a comment. Thanks cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have wrong selector for options. I suggest you to use id as selector for html select. Smth like that

```
$('#ordersdetailpartyloafsandwich1ID').find('option[value=1]').attr('selected', true);
    $('#ordersdetailpartyloafsandwich1ID').val('1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the selected attribute in your desired option like this:

```
<option value="Saumon" selected>Saumon</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @marcq you don't have to write too much of code for this you can simply add the value of that specific option something like that

```
$('select[name="child-partyloafsandwich1ID"]').val(1);
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes on your fiddle:

1. You did not include jQuery.
2. Your select's name is `child-partyloafsandwich1ID` not `name`.
3. The `:eq` selector accepts a zero-based index.
4. Since your element have an `id`, you should use it as selector.

Now, knowing all of this, read 
[Set the selected index of a Dropdown using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314245/set-the-selected-index-of-a-dropdown-using-jquery)

By the way, in this case you do not need jQuery to select that option. You can do it as follows:

```js
document.getElementById('ordersdetailpartyloafsandwich1ID').selectedIndex = 1;
```

```html
<div class="form-group" style="display: block;">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Sandwiches 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select id="ordersdetailpartyloafsandwich1ID" name="child-partyloafsandwich1ID" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Saumon</option>
      </select>
      <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 100px;">
        <span class="selection">
          <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-ordersdetailpartyloafsandwich1ID-container">
            <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-ordersdetailpartyloafsandwich1ID-container" title="Saumon">Saumon</span>
          <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
          </span>
        </span>
        <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```