# Button Event Doesn't Work If a Class is Added on Select Dropdown Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-plugins

I am working on something like there will be select dropdowns. a datatable below will be filtered as per dropdown selection. And there's a button - Reset, in which if its pressed the filter and sorting will be back to normal. Problem is when I reset table, which changes dropdown value and text, it doesn't change the selected option text - view all (when reset), but value works fine.

Select Dropdown

```
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            Order Status
        </div>
    </div><!-- input-group-prepend -->
    <select name="orderStatus" id="orderStatus" class="statusbox SlectBox form-control">
        <?php echo status(); ?>
    </select>
```

Reset Button

```
$('#resetTable').click(function() {
    $("select.statusbox").val($("select.statusbox option:first").val()).change();       
});
```

where I am making the mistake? Video: streamable.com/fdz5q1

Comment: Please if select is binding properly. Or share you HTML after binding.

Comment: Please check updated @PuneetGoel

Comment: is it done r you want me to check?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can some of the below things as per this solution:

[Set the selected index of a Dropdown using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314245/set-the-selected-index-of-a-dropdown-using-jquery/1314266)

Let me know if case you want more help.